# Can I grow an Oak Live Tree in a large container to keep it around 20 ft high?

Tags: oak

I’m new here. My partner and I are getting married and we are relandscaping our garden as our wedding gift. He loves Coast Live Oaks (Quercus agrifolia) and it’ll mean a lot to us if we can plant one or two. That area of the garden is about 30 feet wide. Way to small for a tree that grows up to 85 feet high and 35 feet wide. 
Can we plant a Coast Live Oak in a big container, wether above or under ground, to keep the roots and the tree about 20 feet high and 15 feet wide? Thanks in advance for your answers.[image: Garden now]

Comment: what is your location, your growing zone? Plants in pots are being in a colder zone so we need know how cold it gets

Comment: It might be feasible if you are willing to pollard regularly

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not, not even in the medium term. The tree is unlikely to reach the size you mention contained in a pot because of root restriction; whilst it may remain healthy for a year or three if grown from seed or a small sapling, it will not do well contained in such a manner. This is one of those trees that produces a large and deep tap root, as well as large lateral roots, and growth of the taproot won't be possible in a container; this will compromise the tree's growth early in its life. If you bury the container, the only way the tree will grow on well is if it manages to punch through the bottom of the container and access the soil around and about. It is likely to do that, and when it does, it might as well be growing directly in the ground, in terms of height and spread as it grows. Burying the container confers no advantage in terms of restricting its growth otherwise.

Comment: There are oak bonsai, so you may get in a container, but probably it is not what you are asking (in such case add it in the question).

Answer (score 1):

We live in Whittier California. We have an oak tree in a container that is 18 years old. Have had to get much larger containers through the years. The current container weighs about 500 pounds. The oak tree is currently about 12 feet high and 10 ft wide. It is possible to do what you want to do.